# Groupby with sum over columns to get frequency of each item

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Please see attached image which include the form I would like to get][1]I am trying to get the frequency of days grouped by its ID. So I would like to know: [2] The total number of days for each ID and [2] the frequency of each day per ID.
So it should be look like this (see attached image):

On top of that I tried the following:

`number = data.groupby(by=['ID, Date_Time']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)`

but this on gives me a different data frame that I can't add it to the original on "data"

````
data = pd.DataFrame({
'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
'Date_Time': ['2010-01-01 12:01:00', '2010-01-01 01:27:33', 
'2010-04-02 12:01:00', '2010-04-01 07:24:00', '2011-01-01 12:01:00', 
'2011-01-01 01:27:33', '2013-01-01 12:01:00', '2014-01-01 12:01:00', 
'2014-01-01 01:27:33', '2015-01-01 01:27:33', '2016-01-01 01:27:33', 
'2011-01-01 01:28:00']})```
````

Comment: please add your data as text to your main post. Add it in its current form and what you expect it to be, don't post it as an answer

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and your expected result in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the frequency of the ID (columns `Total_# of days perID`):

```
for ID in set(data['ID']):
    data.loc[data['ID']==ID,'Total_# of days perID'] = len(data.loc[data['ID']==ID])
```

Inserting the frequency of the days within each ID (column `freq_days_perID`):

```
for ID in set(data['ID']):
    for date in set(pd.to_datetime(data.loc[data['ID']==ID,'Date_Time']).dt.date):
        days_frequency = len(data.loc[(data['ID']==ID) & (pd.to_datetime(data['Date_Time']).dt.date == date)])
        data.loc[(data['ID']==ID) & (pd.to_datetime(data['Date_Time']).dt.date == date), 'freq_days_perID'] = days_frequency
```

The final output:

```
    ID  Date_Time            Total_# of days perID      freq_days_perID
0   1   2010-01-01 12:01:00  4.0                        2.0
1   1   2010-01-01 01:27:33  4.0                        2.0
2   1   2010-04-02 12:01:00  4.0                        1.0
3   1   2010-04-01 07:24:00  4.0                        1.0
4   2   2011-01-01 12:01:00  2.0                        2.0
5   2   2011-01-01 01:27:33  2.0                        2.0
6   3   2013-01-01 12:01:00  1.0                        1.0
7   4   2014-01-01 12:01:00  2.0                        2.0
8   4   2014-01-01 01:27:33  2.0                        2.0
9   5   2015-01-01 01:27:33  1.0                        1.0
10  6   2016-01-01 01:27:33  2.0                        1.0
11  6   2011-01-01 01:28:00  2.0                        1.0
```

Comment: Hi Dave. Could you please flag this as the correct answer, just for the increase in reputation? Thanks